# How to serialize/deserialize object in android with LinkedList of other custom objects inside?

Tags: android, android-widget

How to serialize/deserialize object in android with list of other objects inside ? I done this with sqlite to manually save all fields and in another table objects from list but I am curious is there any easier method.

Answer (score 1):

A fairly easy way to serialize/deserialize an object would be to use JSON and a wrapper like [Google Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) that will take care of all the hard work for you.

You haven't mentioned the purpose of serializing/deserializing these nested objects, but Gson will give you a nice little (json parseable) text file to do with as you please.